# HTML - Form action:tomail - send questions and data?

Tags: html, forms, post

I'm new to HTML coding, so I apologize in advance if the question might seem dull or repetitive...

I need to create an HTML form that sends out an EMAIL with the form content (question) and answers, as a sort of receipt, to the admin and the other relevant people that user might add in the attached mail.

I cannot use any external service, so I thought a simple HTML mail with form code will suffice.

When it comes to `<form action=...>` i tried with mailto as multidata-form, but it gives me back only the answers. How can I "export" the form with the questions and answers? (the requirement is that I can use nothing more than the email client (Outlook), any suggestions are welcome)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also ask the first question first, and depending on answer ask the second question in another question

Answer (score 0):

> i tried with mailto as multidata-form, but it gives me back only the answers. How can I "export" the form with the questions and answers?

Forms send the data in the form controls.

They don't send data in labels.

If you want to send the questions, then you need to put them in form control in **addition** to labels.

You could use `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: Is this worth an answer? Poor question without HTML example

Comment: sorry mplunjian i'm new to stackoverflow, but anyway the question is poor because the HTML would have been a classic form implementation with action:mailto. I don't think people need to see it to answer my question, it's an open question to understand more strategies on HTML Forms

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Quentin I tried with label and it kind does what I had in mind, thanks. I still think that the output is not user-friendly, maybe I shall pursue a different path. Is there anything I can use with html without the need of a backend or service?

Cheers!

Comment: No. This is why everyone users server side code to do this. It is the only approach that is reliable and the only approach that gives you any degree of control over the formatting.